# SSRS multivalue parameter to multi-row table

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I want to generate a multi-row table with a multi-value parameter.

The only thing i can do now is passing the specified parameter into every row like below:

```
=Parameters!P.Value(0)  
=Parameters!P.Value(1)  
...  
=Parameters!P.Value(n)
```

Is there a way to do it dynamically?

Comment: Please supply inputs and expected out puts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question, the only I can think of is converting the parameter array into xml in a dataset, and then converting it into a table via xml nodes.

The data set parameter (lets call it @par) then should be set in a expression as:

```
= "<n>" + join(Parameters!P.Value,"</n><n>") + "</n>"
```

Then the query for the dataset will be this:

```
declare @parxml xml = @par
Select p.query('./text()')
from @parxml.nodes('/n') as T(p)
```

this will provide a table with one row per each selected parameter value.

Comment: cool, it works like a charm ... easier than my solution for sure

Answer (score 1):

Finally i've found a good solution.
(remember P is a multi-value-parameter .. es. P=a;b;c;d;e)

First add a dataset that points to a table(database) made of a numeric progressive field (id) like this: (remember to load the table with a number of rows >= to the possibile number of values in your multi-value-parameter ... or simply load like 10000 rows and i think you'll be ok)

[image]

then in the report add a table with: the field **id** (from Dataset1) and the following expression (representing your parameter P) :

```
=Parameters!P.Value(Fields!id.Value)
```

[image]

now if you run the report you'll get something like this:

[image]

To remove the #Error rows simply filter the entire table like below, and you are done!

[image]

Comment: It's a good solution +1, but have you tried the solution I posted? it doesn't need to create a table or filter anything and it's just a four lines of code