# SSRS How to pass values from multiple value parameter to a temp table?

Tags: reporting-services

My report has two datasets, ds_1 and ds_2, pulling from two different SQL servers.

ds_1 has the following query:

```
SELECT Patient_ID
FROM   Server1.dbo.Patient_Table
WHERE  Provider_ID = @Provider
```

@Provider is a parameter entered into the report by the user. This query works fine.

I then have another parameter @Patients which is hidden, multivalue, and based on the Patients value returned from ds_1

ds_2 has the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Server2.dbo.Records
WHERE  PatID IN (@Patients)
```

@Patients might have a thousand or more values in it. I believe this solution works, but the execution time is very slow.

I'm hoping to populate a temp table from the values in @Patients, and then join that temp table to Server2.dbo.Records. I think the execution time would be faster, but would need to test it to be sure.

I imagine ds_2 would be something like:

```
SELECT Value
INTO   #Temp
FROM   STRING_SPLIT(@Patients, ',')

SELECT *
FROM   Server2.dbo.Records r
JOIN   #Temp t on t.Value = r.PatID
```

However, that gives the error:

```
An error occurred during local report processing.
An error has occurred during report processing.
Query execution failed for dataset 'ds_2'
Procedure or function STRING_SPLIT has too many arguments specified.
```

I tried changing ds_2 to something simple, like:

```
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Patients, ',')
```

and still get the same error.

If there's a better way to pass the results of ds_1 to a parameter or temp table in ds_2, I'm willing to give it a try. If it matters, I'm not able to make any changes to the SQL servers themselves.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the XML way would work better. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41953592/ssrs-multivalue-parameter-to-multi-row-table

Comment: Maybe parametrize the report by dates of the patients? Added functionality that maybe lead to better performance?

Comment: The problem with the error is that the @Patients string has commas separating the values. Maybe replace them? `SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(@Patients, ',', '|'), '|')`